# What is the difference between << and & in boost serialisation library?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Using both if them does the same thing for me, serialise data without any problems.
Which one should I use and in which case?

Answer (score 1):

An output archive is similar to an output data stream. Data can be saved to the archive with either the `<<` or the `&` operator:

```
ar << data;
ar & data;
```

An input archive is similar to an input datastream. Data can be loaded from the archive with either the `>>` or the `&` operator.

```
ar >> data;
ar & data;
```

When these operators are invoked for primitive data types, the data is simply saved/loaded to/from the archive. When invoked for class data types, the class serialize function is invoked. Each serialize function is uses the above operators to save/load its data members. This process will continue in a recursive manner until all the data contained in the class is saved/loaded.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html